# How to read different .txt file columns in different strings in Python?

Tags: python, file

I have the following `.txt` file which is called `answers.txt`:

```
0 identify
0 organizations
0 that
0 participate
0 in
0 international
0 criminal
0 activity
0 the
0 activity
0 and
0 if
0 possible
0 collaborating
0 organizations
0 and
0 countries
0 involved
1 is
1 the
1 disease
1 of
1 poliomyelitis
1 polio
1 under
1 control
1 in
1 the
1 world
```

The first column plays the role `id`, that means, columns with the same `id` belong to the same sentence as follows:

```
answer_0 = 'identify organizations that participate in international criminal activity and if possible collaborating organizations and countries involved'

answer_1= 'is the disease of poliomyelitis polio under control in the world'
```

So far I have been able to read each line of my document by using the following code:

```
separator=' '
string=[]
for line in open("answers.txt"):
    columns = line.split(separator)
    if len(columns) >= 2:
        print (columns[1])
```

But I don't want the words belonging to the same sentence separate but together in the same string as in `answer_0` and in `answer_1`. Ideally, I would like to have `list=[answer_0, answer_1]`.

Comment: Could you pull this off by storing the answers in a dictionary where the ID is the key and the value is a string? Then you could just append the additional words to the string as they are encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, I suggest you read the id at the beginning of each line and store the strings in a dictionary. Like so:

```
answer_dict = {}
for line in open("answers.txt"):
    line_values = line.split()
    try:
        answer_dict[int(line_values[0])] += " " + line_values[1]
    except:
        answer_dict[int(line_values[0])] = line_values[1]
```

And then you can do whatever you want with the dictionary. To make it into a list:

```
answer_list = []
for id in answer_dict.keys():
    answer_list += answer_dict[id]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be looking for is in the lines of :

```
def fileReader(filename):
    f_obj = open(filename,"r")
    table_dict = {}
    seperator = " "
    for line in f_obj:
        id, word = line.split(seperator)
        existing_list = table_dict.get("answer_"+id, "")
        existing_list += " " + word
        table_dict["answer_"+id] = existing_list
    return table_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no need for dictionary. When you split the row, it creates a list of sub strings where 1st element would be the column number indicating the sentence number and another element would have the substring of your sentence. So you can generate your sentence on the go which would save the Space Complexity needed by Dictionary and maybe somewhat faster too.

```
separator=' '
string=[]
for line in open("answers.txt"):
    columns = line.split(separator)
    if columns[0]== '0':
        answer_0 += " "+ columns[1]
    elif columns[0]== '1':
        answer_1 += " "+ columns[1]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the sentences on the fly. For example:

```
sentences = dict()
for line in open('answers.txt'):
    n, word = line.split(' ')
    sentences.setdefault(n, []).append(word)
```

Then each sentence has a key in `sentences` and is a list of words, you can join them, for example for the sentence whose id is 1:

```
' '.join(sentences[1])
```

For all sentences:

```
for n, words in sentences.items():
   print(' '.join(words))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
columns = []
string1 = []
string2 = []
for line in open("answers.txt"):
    columns = line.split(separator)
    if columns[0] == “0”:
        string1.append(columns[1])
    else:
        string2.append(columns[1])
answer1 = ‘’.join(string1)
answer2 = ‘’.join(string2)
print answer1
print answer2
```